# Kyocera FS-1120D printer installation

Tags: printing

Every attempt to install Kyocera FS-1120D printer driver in Ubuntu 18-4 has failed.
Downloading the driver installation from Kyocera's website and attempting to install using 'kyodialog_5.0-0_i386.deb results in no available printer. Installing it manually in terminal using either aptitude or apt-get install result in missing dependencies and no printer to add.

Brute force copying Kyocera_FS-1120D.PPD to `/usr/share/cups/model`  or  `/usr/share/cups/model/Kyocera` does not provide any printer to be added in Settings > Devices > Printers. I am surprised that I can't get a printer to work even though I have the '.PPD' file.

I have also tried CUPS both in a terminal and in a browser (CUPS > admin), no luck. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure about 1120, but FS-1118MFP works with driver from repository and with `system-config-printer`. Did you tried to click on *Provide PPD file* in *Change Driver* dialog and specify it manually?

Comment: @N0rbert Thanks for the suggestion, I didn't know system-config-printer. However, the Change Driver dialog appear only once the printer is installed. When I run system-config-printer in a terminal, I get a 'Printers - localhost' dialog saying 'There are no printers configured yet.' 'Add'. The only way around would be to install another model and then introduce the 1120 ppd file - not an obvious approach.

Answer (score 0):

I tried

> Settings | Printers | Tools Cog | Printer Details

and then

> Install PPD File | Location
>   and in location pasted a PPD in my home folder. 
>   This didn't work, perhaps because of permissions.

I also tried direct copy of PPD file into /usr/share/cups/model, and that didn't work.

But after I did `system-config-printer`, the printer because visible. I suspect that

> Settings | Printers | Tools Cog | Printer Details
>   assumes that the correct PPD file is **already** in the correct location.